# Read in a subset of csv columns by name

Tags: r, tidyverse, read.table, read.csv

I have dozens of CSV files of varied length. Some csv files have 18 columns, and some others have 9. They share the same universe of column names. I would like to read in some of the columns of each file, by variable name.

Here is a small example of what I am dealing with.

```
df1 <- tibble(a = 1:2, b = letters[1:2], c = NA, e=7:8)
df2 <- tibble(a = 8:9, b = letters[7:8], e = 8:9, c = NA)
df3 <- tibble(a = 8:9, b = letters[7:8], c = NA, d=5:6, e=7:8)
```

I would like to pull in the columns a,b AND e. I cannot specify column position because they are in different position in each dataset. I would need to use the variable names within each file to read in those columns.

This is the function I started with to read in only the columns that I want. I can't really use this because the column positions are so different for each csv file that it is pulling in the wrong columns.

```
read_fun = function(path){
  test = read.csv(path, sep=",", header=F, fill = TRUE, colClasses = c(rep("NULL",2), "character",rep("NULL",2),
                                                                                   rep("character",14), rep("NULL",5)),
                  skip = 1, nrows = 17)
  test$question = path
  test
}
```

I know col.names allows you to **re-name** the columns as you are reading it in, that is not helpful to me.

Does R have a way of reading in files by the variable name of each file?

Something like:

```
test = read.csv("fileA.csv", sep = ",", col_names = c("a","b","e"))
```

Any help, please!

Comment: ... one option would be the `vroom` package. function `vroom::vroom` allows you to select columns via argument `col_select`,

Comment: How OK reading each file (entirely) , then subset the column a, b AND e and return the whole thing as a list or dataframe?

Comment: @stefan I can't use vroom to read files in can I? I can only use it to manipulate the file after it has been read in?

Comment: @Liman, I have dozens of files, I need to read them in at once and then rowbind them afterwards, I can't rowbind files of differing length :(

Comment: @NewBee. Sure can you read the files using vroom::vroom. That's what it is meant for. (; I checked. Reads only the columns you specify via `col_select`. Try it out.

Comment: @stefan Thank you, this worked!

Comment: data.table’s `fread()` function has a `select` parameter for specifying the names of the columns you want to import from a text tile.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than post filtering, as in @teru's earlier answer, read time filtering is available from [readr 2.0.0](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/blob/915ca8c6e9566fcb9880e3ef93187fe70000d8c6/NEWS.md) (released July 2021):

```
read_csv(path, col_select = c("a", "b", "e"))
```

readr 2 is vroom based so this is just picking up the pathway @stefan noted in the OP comments.

Answer (score 0):

If each file is not so big and it doesn't take time to read, read-first-and-select strategy would work. In case auto type detection doesn't work properly, you might need to add `mutate` at the end of the chain to adjust column type.

```
library(tidyverse)

read_fun <- function(path) {
  read_csv(path) %>%
    select(a, b, e)
}
```

If you want to combine all data.frame into one, use `map_dfr`:

```
df_combined <-
  c("file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv") %>%
  map_dfr(funcion(path) {
    read_csv(path) %>%
      select(a, b, e) %>%
      mutate(a = as.numeric(a),
             b = as.character(b),
             e = as.numeric(e))
  })
```